# How to initialize an array of objects from an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino

I have an array of constant bytes. From that array, I want to initialize an array of objects. I tried the following code but didn't produce the expected result.

```cpp
const byte VALUES [] = {1, 2, 3};

class MyClass {
    public:
        MyClass(byte value) {
            _value = value;
        }
    private:
        byte _value;
};

MyClass myObjects[] = {VALUES};
```

I managed to do it by using the following code:

```cpp
const byte VALUES [] = {1, 2, 3};

class MyClass {
    public:
        MyClass() {}
        MyClass(byte value) {
            _value = value;
        }
    private:
        byte _value;
};

MyClass *myObjects = new MyClass[3];

for (byte i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    myObjects[i] = MyClass(VALUES[i]);
}
```

Is there any more elegant way of initializing the array of objects? Without loops and empty constructor, preferably.

Comment: `MyClass myObjects[] = {VALUES[0], VALUES[1], VALUES[2]};`

Comment: Wouldn't be that pretty when `VALUES` has more element, would it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use std::array to do it. No need in manual array management here.

```
std::array<MyClass, 3> ma = {1, 2, 3};
```

Comment: You didn't use the constant byte array and this doesn't work in Arduino.